# About some isomorphism of right R-modules as abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules, abelian-groups

Let $M$ and $V$ be right $R$-modules. Let $D=End_{R}(M)=Hom_{R}(M,M)$. Suppose that

$Hom_{R}(V,Hom_{R}(M,V)\otimes_{D}M)) \cong Hom_{R}(V,V)$

as abelian groups, where this isomorphism is given by

$g \mapsto Tg\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
 (g \in Hom_{R}(V,Hom_{R}(M,V)\otimes_{D}M))$

with $T:Hom_{R}(M,V)\otimes_{D}M \to V$

by $T(f \otimes m) = f(m)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (f \in Hom_{R}(M,V), \, m \in M)$

My question: Does the above isomorphism imply that $T$ is an isomorphpism of abelian groups, that is

$Hom_{R}(M,V)\otimes_{D}M\cong V$

If not, can you please give me a counter example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The one that comes to mind is -

\begin{align}
&R = \mathbb{Z}, V = \mathbb{Z}, M = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},   D= End_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)\\
&\implies Hom_{R}(M,V) = Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) = 0\\
&\implies Hom_{R}(M,V) \bigotimes_{D}M = Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) \bigotimes_{D}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}  = 0\\
&\implies Hom_{R}(M,V)\bigotimes_{D} M = 0 \neq \mathbb{Z} = V
\end{align}

Although it doesn't matter, $D = End_{\mathbb{Z}}(M) = End_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: There is a mistake in the second line $Hom_{Z}(Z,Z/2Z)=Z/2Z$ not 0

Comment: Edited Thanks :)

Comment: also the forth line I think need some changes(multiplying by tensor M)

Comment: Yes, now it is fixed I think. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I think the choices for $R,M,V$ do not satisfy the first isomorphism mentioned in the question